# How to append a line of text to a file in SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

i want to append a line of text to a text file in SQLCMD
The line of text is 'Have a nice day'
i have following command prompt.

SQLCMD -STest -Usa -PPassword1 -i" have a nice day" >> c:\log.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a batch file (`.bat`) with your `SQLCMD` command followed by a `ECHO` command and run this file.

The contents of the file should be something like this:

```
SQLCMD -STest -Usa -PPassword1 >> C:\log.txt

ECHO "Have a nice day!" >> C:\log.txt
```

You can also try to play with `@ECHO ON` or `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning of the file depending if you run the .bat file from Command Prompt.